# Unknown error from PostCSS plugin..possible bug

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, postcss, autoprefixer

There is an unknown error from PostCSS plugin,giving rise to an error.

My angular versions:

```
    _                      _                 ____ _     ___
   / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
  / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
 / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
/_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
               |___/

Angular CLI: 1.6.2
Node: 6.12.2
OS: linux x64
Angular: 5.1.3
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

@angular/cli: 1.6.2
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.36
@angular-devkit/core: 0.0.22
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.42
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.9.2
@schematics/angular: 0.1.11
@schematics/schematics: 0.0.11
typescript: 2.4.2
webpack: 3.10.0
```

Now when I run the project using ng serve or ng build:

This happens:

> 13% building modules 31/40 modules 9 active 
>       .../webpack/hot nonrecursive /^./log$/Unknown error from PostCSS 
>       plugin.Your current PostCSS version is 6.0.15, but autoprefixer uses 
>       5.2.18. **Perhaps this is the source of the error below.**
>
> 91% additional chunk assets processingError: ENOENT: no such file or 
>       directory, open '/home/telekha-01/workspace/rajtelekha-survey-track-
>       web-de11d86a7c75/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js'
>       at Error (native)

I've tried updating PostCSS and autoprefixer,and again when I run the project it gives the **same error**

Researched on various other sites and stackoverflow as well but can't find  a solution.
In [github](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9029), they say it is a possible bug needs to be fixed. Can't clearly understand what was happening there.

If it is a bug, is it fixed? Please find me a solution.

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I could get rid of the error.

I had to downgrade bootstrap to clear the issue.

I downgraded bootstrap with following steps.

Uninstall bootstrap@4.0.0-beta.3:

```
npm uninstall bootstrap --save
```

Then installed bootstrap@4.0.0-beta.2:

```
npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-beta.2 --save
```

This did the trick !

Comment: tried a lot of solutions but this works. thanks alot :).